# Получить список регионов, в которых находятся объекты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, карты

Есть список объектов и их координаты на карте яндекса.
Надо получить список регионов в которых эти объекты находятся(ввиде массива строк).
В мануалах пока не нашёл.
Помогите ссылкой, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, речь об обратном геокодировании. Вот ссылки (предположу, что речь про api 2.0):
http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/dg/concepts/geocoding.xml

И пример из песочницы: [Поиск по карте](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/geocode).